# Kohana & Form Helper - Default Value in Dropdown

Tags: kohana

```
$x=array('a','b','c');
echo form::dropdown('test', $x, 'b');
```

I'm using the Kohana form helper to build forms, but I've hit a snag.  The above test code doesn't display the default value as it should, as written in the docs.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the key of the array, not the value, to determine what default value to show.

Answer (score 1):

Your array should be set up like this:

```
$x = array('a'=>'a', 'b'=>'b', 'c'=>'c');
```

By setting the array the way you are doing it your keys are all numeric.  If you want the keys to be numeric you would need to have a number for your default value:

```
echo form::dropdown('test', $x, 2)
```

Either one of these changes would be ok depending on how you want your application set up.